# Request response object and content type annotation convention

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I am using asp.net core 2.2.6, I am not clear what the expected convention is regarding the use of [ProducesAttribute](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ProducesAttribute.cs) and [ProducesResponseTypeAttribute](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ProducesResponseTypeAttribute.cs) annotations with [ProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-2.2?view=aspnetcore-2.2#problem-details-support). Without the annotations, an API behaves as expected and the content types are applied to the appropriate return types, however when using the annotations to assist with Swashbuckle, the behavior is restrictive.

Consider the following for example:

```
[HttpPut]
[Consumes("application/json")]
[Produces("application/json", "application/problem+json")]
// [Produces("application/json", Type = typeof(ProblemDetails))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromBody] SomeModel model, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // ...
}
```

When an error occurs and a `ProblemDetails` instance is returned, the default handling is overridden and the return type is set to "application/json".

The `Produces` attribute can correlate a single object and content type, however it does not let you define more than one instance. The solution is to use several `ProducesResponseType` attributes which let you declare a type (though it is correctly inferred and not necessary), however this attribute does not facilitate content type ([as declared in source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c23b9feb19a9809a82e541427028b63ca66fa847/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ProducesResponseTypeAttribute.cs#L49)).

The behavior is clear as per [ObjectResultExecutor](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c23b9feb19a9809a82e541427028b63ca66fa847/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ObjectResultExecutor.cs#L171-L182).

The "application/problem+json" content type is not even shown by swagger-ui as one of the available content types by default, so filtering the media types in an operation filter is not possible (you could grab the first `ProblemDetails` reference and rebuild the collection with a new content type key).

What is the most elegant solution for Swashbuckle that wont introduce undesirable behavior in the api, but constrain the swagger ui to reveal the desired content types?

Comment: Struggling with the same. I think it is a bug in ASP.NET Core, filed an issue. See: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19510